# Broadcast BLE Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcast

i'm developing an ionic app that uses a service running in background for scan devices with ble, thanks to cordova-plugin-ble-central I can successfully make the scan, but I also need to use my smartphone to broadcast ble signals so other smartphones with my app can find it. 
Does anyone knows a plugin or something to use to make it?

Comment: visibility is on?

Comment: @Nirus yes it is

Comment: Try https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-peripheral. Currently it only supports iOS. Android support is possible, it just needs to be written.

Comment: Version 1.0.0 of cordova-plugin-ble-peripheral adds Android support